# arduino uno freezes

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

Is there a reason why my Arduino Uno freezes after a few minutes of running with power coming from a usb cable connected to my pc?

```
#include <GY6050.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <VarSpeedServo.h>

#define angle1 20
#define angle2 90

#define Sensor_BL A0
#define Sensor_BR A1

VarSpeedServo servo;

GY6050 gyro1(0x68);
GY6050 gyro2(0x69);

int X = 0;
int Y = 0;

int y1_axis = 0;
int y2_axis = 0;

int sensorBL;
int sensorBR;

int speed = 0;
int angle = 0;

int prev_y1_axis = 0;
int y1_hold = 0;
unsigned long timer;
int start = 1;
byte step = 0;
String steps , laststep;
int freq;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  gyro1.initialisation();
  gyro2.initialisation();
  delay(100);
  servo.attach(8);
  servo.write(90);
}

void loop() {
  y1_axis = gyro1.refresh('A', 'Y');
  y2_axis = gyro2.refresh('A', 'Y');
  sensorBL = analogRead(Sensor_BL);
  sensorBR = analogRead(Sensor_BR);

  //0 right - 90 centr - 180 left

  if (sensorBL > 250) {
    speed = map( sensorBL , 0 , 1023 , 0 , 255);
    if (sensorBL < 700) { //less pressure 90+20=110
      servo.write(95 , speed);
      angle = 95;
    }
    else if (sensorBL > 700) { //more pressre 90+90 = 180
      servo.write(105 , speed);
      angle = 105;
    }
  }
  else if (sensorBR > 250) {
    speed = map( sensorBR , 0 , 1023 , 0 , 255);
    if (sensorBR < 700) {
      servo.write(95 , speed);
      angle = 95;
    }
    else if (sensorBR > 700) {
      servo.write(105 , speed);
      angle = 105;
    }
  }
  else if ((start == 0 || millis() - timer > 800) && y1_axis > -90 && y1_axis < 20 && y2_axis > -90 && y2_axis < 20 && sensorBL < 10 && sensorBR < 20) //flat dead end no servo movement - center position - can we separate on different lines the pressure sensor and accell so that I can set the dead end value separately for the press sens and acc ?
  {
    servo.write( 85 , 15);
    //Serial.println("Servo goes to zero");
    start = 1;
    step = 0;
    angle = 0;
    steps = "0";
  }
  else if ((y1_axis < 60 & y1_axis >40) && (step == 0 || step == 2))
  {
    step = 1;
    steps = "1";
  }
  else if ((y2_axis < 55 & y2_axis > 40) && (step == 0 || step == 1))
  {
    step = 2;
    steps = "2";
  }

  if (!steps.equals(laststep)) {

    if ((step == 1 || step == 2) && millis() - timer <= 700) {
      if (freq > 1) {
        servo.write(70 , 20);
        angle = 70;
      }
      else {
        servo.write(78 , 20);
        angle = 78;
      }
      freq++;
    }
    else if ((step == 1 || step == 2 && millis() - timer > 750)) {
      servo.write(78 , 20);
      angle = 78;
      freq = 0;
    }

    timer = millis();
  }
  //Serial.println("Y1: " + String(y1_axis) + " Y2: " + String(y2_axis) + " S1: " + String(sensorBL) + " S2: " + String(sensorBR) + " Millis: " + String(millis() - timer) + " Step: " + String(steps) + " Last: " + String(laststep) + " Angle: " + String(angle));
  Serial.println("Millis: " + String(millis() - timer) + " Angle: " + String(angle));

  laststep = steps;

}
```

---

I am using the pc usb power cable to power on the arduino and 2 accelerometers and one SG90 hobby servomotor. Would the best way power on the 1 servo with its own power supply ?

What power supply would you suggest for 1 servomotor?

When not connected to the pc, I use 9v battery to power on together the arduino and the one servomotor

thanks!

---

It is the part of the code for moving forward and backward in this locomotion system I came up with

https://github.com/marcob2178/Arduino-Based-Game-Locomotion

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYTlF2GhXpQ

Sensors are mounted on shoes

Comment: what does it do when it is working correctly?

Comment: Is it possible the servo motors draw too much current?

Comment: Is your 9V battery a 9V block battery? If yes, you should move to a different battery type, since 9V block batteries are meant for low power applications. They cannot provide much current and any motor (a servo is also a motor) can draw loads of current (especially when stalled)

Comment: yes, it is a 9v block battery. Would a 6AA 9V Battery solution be enough to power the arduino uno or mega + 2 accelerometers + 1 servo motor ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said or shown how your servo is powered but both the Arduino power supply is limited and your computer's USB power has a protective limit. You can power an SG90 hobby servo from the Arduino, but any larger servo needs its own supply, with only the PWM signal being taken from the Arduino. If the servo (or any other device or collection of devices) exceeds the capabilities of the Arduino's power supply, its output voltage will fall. One of the consequences of that is that the MCU stops. Or if your computer's USB supply is exceeded, it will shut down protectively.

My guess is you're powering your motor from the Arduino and it's starving the MCU.